# Data Extraction From the Column Dynamically

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this data in Google Sheets.

```
Young, Yamen (09/21/1960 M)
Address: 012 Hendrix Street Brooklyn NY 12207
Phone: 917-621-0000(Home) 917-000-8989(Mobile)
Insurance: CHIP(U4024563201) Location: (Far Rockaway) Type: Radiology - Results Follow-up
Memo:
Status: Confirmed
```

in number of rows. I want to extract multiple information from this Data into readable format like this:

[image]

Here are my formulas that i have developed so far but these are not able to work as i want.

```
C3 =LEFT(A2,(FIND("(",A2,1)-1))
D3 =MID(A2,FIND("(",A2,1)+1,10)
E3 =MID(A5,FIND(":",A5)+1,256)
F3 =MID(A5,FIND("(",A5,1)+1,11)
```

Here is attached sheet where i am trying to create an formula which can extract it dynamically. Any help towards the problem will be appreciated.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PUUWBwV4iLvyKEIjKwPiD7oiHl77Y6rJQ98d6Wxlg-s/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use custom function where you can use regular expression to extract string within a string and handle complex patterns.

**To write a custom function:**

1. Create or open a spreadsheet in Google Sheets.
2. Select the menu item Tools > Script editor.
3. Delete any code in the script editor and paste the code provided below
4. At the top, click Save save.

**To use the custom function:**

1. Click the cell where you want to use the function.
2. Type an equals sign (=) followed by the function name and any input value — for example, =DOUBLE(A1) — and press Enter.
3. The cell will momentarily display Loading..., then return the result.

**Code:**

```
function extractData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1);
  var array = range.getValues(); //get data in spreadsheet A2:A49

  var filteredArr = array.filter(function(obj){ // this function will remove empty subarray
   return obj[0] != "";
  });
  var newArr = filteredArr.flat(); //convert 2d array into 1d
  const groupedArr = [];
  while(newArr.length) groupedArr.push(newArr.splice(0,6)); //group array by 6 elements, this will convert the array into 2d
  var finalArr = [];

  for( var i = 0; i < groupedArr.length; i++ ){
    var tempArr = [];
    for( var j = 0; j < groupedArr[0].length; j++ ){
      var nameRegex = /^(.+)(?=\s?\(.+\))/;
      var dobRegex = /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/;
      var insuranceRegex = /^Insurance:\s([A-Za-z0-9\s]+)\(.+/;
      var idRegex = /^Insurance:\s[A-Za-z0-9\s]+\((\w+)\)/;
      if( j == 0 ){
        var name = groupedArr[i][j].match(nameRegex)[1];
        var dob = groupedArr[i][j].match(dobRegex)[0];
        tempArr.push(name);
        tempArr.push(dob);
      }else if( j == 3){
        var insurance = (groupedArr[i][j].match(insuranceRegex) != null) ? groupedArr[i][j].match(insuranceRegex)[1]:"";
        var id = (groupedArr[i][j].match(idRegex) != null) ? groupedArr[i][j].match(idRegex)[1]:"";
        tempArr.push(insurance);
        tempArr.push(id);
      }
    }
    finalArr.push(tempArr);
  }

  return finalArr;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

### References:

- [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)
- [String.match(regex)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)
- [Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: thank you and I apologize for being late. I was not able to reply because of weekends. But i am receiving an error `TypeError: groupedArr[i][j].match is not a function` on the line 23 that is `var name = groupedArr[i][j].match(nameRegex)[1];`

Comment: @Valiant - I noticed that you edited your spreadsheet and added numbering in column A. If that's the case, you have to change the value of range from `var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1);` to `var range = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1);`.  This is where the script will get its data.  I updated my answer above based on the current spreadsheet you have.